# Simple sequential model with LSTM which doesn't converge

Tags: natural-language-processing, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-networks, long-short-term-memory

I'm actually trying to create a sequential neural network in order to translate a "human" sentence in a "machine" sentence understandable by an algorithm. Like It didn't work, I've try to create a NN that understands whether the input is a unit or not.

Even this NN doesn't work and I don't understand Why. I tried with different optimize/loss/metrics/with Rnn/with LSTM.

So there is one array of unit and one array with lambda words.
I send to the NN :

input -> word in OneHotEncoding where each char is a vector

output -> a vector with a 1 at the relative position of the unit in the array, ex : [0,0,0,1,0]. If It's not a unit, the vector is composed of 0.

I'm actually using LSTM layers and sigmoid activation because I will need it for my "big" NN.

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(13,vocab_size),batch_size=80))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=True)) 
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(6, return_sequences=False))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation="sigmoid"))
model.reset_states()
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer= 'adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
model.fit(encoded_word, my_targets, batch_size=80, epochs=100, validation_data=(encoded_word, my_targets))



Model: "sequential_38"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_57 (LSTM)               (80, 13, 32)              6400      
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_58 (LSTM)               (80, 6)                   936       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_32 (Dense)             (80, 6)                   42        
=================================================================
Total params: 7,378
Trainable params: 7,378
Non-trainable params: 0


Epoch 1/100
10000/10000 [==============================] - 6s 619us/sample - loss: 0.7441 - categorical_accuracy: 0.2898 - val_loss: 0.6181 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.3388
Epoch 2/100
10000/10000 [==============================] - 2s 233us/sample - loss: 0.5768 - categorical_accuracy: 0.3388 - val_loss: 0.5382 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.3388
Epoch 3/100
10000/10000 [==============================] - 2s 229us/sample - loss: 0.5039 - categorical_accuracy: 0.3979 - val_loss: 0.4640 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.5084
Epoch 4/100
10000/10000 [==============================] - 2s 229us/sample - loss: 0.4207 - categorical_accuracy: 0.4759 - val_loss: 0.3709 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.5041
```

My NN is converging towards 0.5 all the time.

Thank you in advance for your answers !